# Spring cloud function - accept query parameter and header

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-function

I have been reading about lambda and spring cloud functions, is there anyway to get hold of query parameters and the headers in the lambda.

I created a function<Message, Customer>, but Message is not holding the query parameter however i see the headers.. Is there any option i can use Supplier but still can access header and query parameter?

Comment: What do you mean by Supplier and access to headers? Supplier implies beginning of things. There is no input of any kind

Comment: Thank you @Oleg for your response. I was trying to implement similar to rest GET endpoint using spring cloud function..using  function/supplier. Initially I tried with functional<Message<String>, Customer> get customer() {}

Comment: Initially I tried with functional<Message<String>, Customer> get customer() {}. I was trying to access the query parameter and header values in message. I saw one of the stack overflow you mentioned message have access to both headers and query parameter however I don't see query parameters. Is there anyway to get the query/path variable in message or any other objects

Comment: Here is the sample project for your reference - https://github.com/nbenjamin/project-samples-serverless-spring-lambda-